# Teradata expand on clause

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to understand the expand on clause.

This one expands to 3 rows:

SEL prd
FROM any_table_with_only_1_row
EXPAND ON PERIOD'(**2020-09-30,2023-09-29**)' AS prd BY ANCHOR PERIOD Year_End

This one expands to 4 rows:

SEL prd
FROM any_table_with_only_1_row
EXPAND ON PERIOD'(**2020-09-29,2023-09-28**)' AS prd BY ANCHOR PERIOD Year_End

Why do they behave differently?

Comment: This is pretty odd behavior.  For the first query, the output from the expand starts with 2020-09-30, but for the second, the output starts with 2019-12-31.

Comment: You may have uncovered a bug.

Comment: Hi again! Do you have any news on this one? @fred Might need to use the expand on some more

Comment: You (or someone at your site) should open a support case with Teradata giving this example. In my opinion, the first expansion is wrong; the second corresponds with the description for ANCHOR PERIOD Year_End.